# How to do Kafka stream transformations (map / flatMap) taking into account values in a Key/Value store?

Tags: scala, apache-kafka

My task is the following:

I am monitoring time synchronization events from a third-party measuring device. This time synchronization is a bit flaky so I want to detect when synchronization stops and issue an alarm.

For this, I am producing the synchronization events to a Kafka topic. I have three different events going on:

1. Synchronization request
2. Synchronization successful
3. Synchronization failed because other device did not respond

So, what I want to do:

- When request is received, and nothing is received after a certain amount of time, I want to issue a "timeout" alarm
- When request is received, and within the timeout period, a success event arrives, I want to issue a "timeout" if no request arrives after the timeout time
- When a failure event arrives, I want to issue the "other device did not respond" alarm

I am currently in the process of setting up a Kafka-Streams application, and I need to store the state in case this application crashes (should not, but I want to be sure), so I set this up the following:

```
val builder = new StreamsBuilder
val storeBuilder = Stores.
  keyValueStoreBuilder(Stores.persistentKeyValueStore("timesync-alarms"),
                       Serdes.String(),
                       logEntrySerde)
builder.addStateStore(storeBuilder)
val eventStream = builder.stream(sourceTopic, Consumed.`with`(Serdes.String(), logEntrySerde))
```

Now, I am stuck. What I basically think I need to do have a `flatMap` function on the eventStream, that, whenever an event arrives:

1. Queries the store for the last event that was processed
2. Decides if an alarm is to be raised
3. Updates the store with the currently-received event
4. Produces the alarm, if any

So, how do I achieve steps 1 and 3 here? Or am I conceptually wrong and have to do it differently?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to use state store directly. You can create two streams - one with sync request events, the second one with sync responses (success, fail) and join them:

```
requestStream.outerJoin(responseStream, (leftVal, rightVal) -> ...,
    JoinWindows.of(timeout), ...);
```

In the case of timeout `rightVal` is null.

If you want to send alarms to a separate topic, you can simply filter the joined stream and write all failures (error responses and timeouts) to the topic. Otherwise you can use `peek()` method and trigger some action inside. Here is a simple example: https://github.com/djarza/football-events/blob/master/football-ui/src/main/java/org/djar/football/ui/projection/StatisticsPublisher.java

Comment: The problems with two streams is that the source is only one stream and I can't easily match them up. The original time synchronization only outputs a text-based log file which I "tail" to a Kafka topic and create the event objects from this. So the responses have a timestamp which is never the same. To reconstruct what was going on I need two consecutive log messages (events) and therefore state. Currently I try using a `ValueTransformerWithKeySupplier`and its corresponding `ValueTransformerWithKey` which allows me to access a store within. I'll write about my success or failure.

Comment: Maybe this problem can be solved with windowed aggregation also. You can group the stream with `windowedBy` and then aggregate. But I think it would be better to have many streams. Think of the input as a two different operations (request and response) that are composed of different fields. If you have only a single topic, you can `branch` the stream into "request" and "response" streams and easily match them using `join` as above. Send me few log entries, I can take a look.

Comment: I can't send any data or any actual code as this is company code and I am not allowed to share it. But using two streams is a good idea, I could match them "fuzzily" as a response usually comes at most a few seconds after the request. `windowedBy` is also a nice idea, although windowing only works based on time, but you could filter out duplicate alarms later.